# Is there a single word for the convergence / divergence of a sequence or sum?

Tags: single-word-requests

In math, we sometimes talk about the *parity* of a number - that is, what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)) succinctly describes as " an integer's inclusion in one of two categories: even or odd." Is there a similar word for convergence / divergence that would allow you to say "Find the X (convergence / divergence) of the sequence"?

Comment: [*Asymptotic behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) is close but gives you more detail than simply convergence or divergence.

Comment: You might say "find the limit." The reason there is unlikely to be a word is because while one can find a convergence value, one cannot find a divergence value. It doesn't make sense to say "find the divergence."

Comment: @Silenus I would've said "Determine if the sequence converges or diverges"; however, I chose what I did hoping it was possible to say something analogous to "Find the parity of the number." That doesn't _necessitate_ a term, of course - especially when "divergent value" is nonsensical, as you said.

Comment: I think the suggestion of @Lawrence (*asymptotic behavior*) deserves to be written up as an answer.

Comment: @Silenus Done :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to is the behaviour of the 'far-reaches' of sequence. In other words, the sequence's **asymptotic behaviour**.

Here's a literal rendering of the term *asymptote* as well as the more abstract application of the concept in asymptotic analysis:

> A line that a curve approaches as you move further away from zero.
>   [- mathisfun.com](http://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/asymptote.html)
>   In mathematical analysis, asymptotic analysis is a method of describing limiting behavior.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis)

Although [analysing asymptotic behaviour](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/example/AsymptoticBehaviorOfAFunction.html) provides information on whether a sequence converges or diverges, it typically goes beyond *just* convergence and divergence, looking for a function that essentially ignores complex behaviour that occurs in early parts of the sequence. It considers the question:

> how is the system behaving "after a long time?"
>   [- Contemporary Calculus](http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/4-6InfiniteLimits.pdf), section 4.6

If you want to restrict the consideration to *just* convergence and divergence, you can rephrase the question to "does the sequence converge?".

Comment: +1. I agree with you mostly, except for your caveat regarding *asymptotic behavior* "going beyond just converge and divergence." If someone told me to "Determine the asymptotic behavior of the sequence", I would simply find out whether or not it converged, and if it did, I would tell them what it converged to. I don't think you need the caveat.

Comment: @Silenus That's an interesting point. I was hoping for that train of thought in the literature, but the ones I came across went all the way to finding the function. That is, the analysis can say a sequence *doesn't converge*, but if it says a sequence converges, there's an expectation to also say *what* it converges to.

Comment: Whoops, I misunderstood what you were getting at. I see the problem now and the reason for the caveat.

Answer (score 0):

Not a word, but a notation that can be unpacked easily. Two actually.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Little-ONotation.html

It is best known for characterizing the divergence of high growth rate behaviors such as the difficulty of solving a problem computationally as the size of the input grows. But it is equally suited to describing convergent series and is used that way in several specialties.

edit fixed link. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation

http://www.math.unl.edu/~s-bbockel1/833-notes/node6.html

Answer (score 0):

Convergence implies that the value of a certain function tends toward a certain value as the argument of the function changes in a certain manner. Divergence implies that no such tendency exists. My conclusion, therefore, is that no single word will serve to denote both possibilities.